# Dask start remote workers programmatically

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I need to create remote workers programmatically and use them for a task, then shut them down.

The sample code given in documentation works fine for what is written:

```
import asyncio
from distributed import Worker, Scheduler, Client
from distributed.scheduler import WorkerState

s = "x.x.x.x:8786" # remote IP, not local, started from command line.

async def f():
    async with Worker(s) as w1, Worker(s) as w2:
        async with Client(s, asynchronous=True) as client:
            future = client.submit(lambda x: x + 1, 10)
            result = await future
            print(result)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(f())
```

Let's say I have `n` different machines other than dask scheduler - `ip1, ip2, ..ipn`. Now, I am facing 2 problems with this:

1. After connecting to remote Scheduler, I want to create workers on multiple machines. Let's say `ip1, ip2, ip3`. Tried using both `host` and `contact_address` params in `Worker` creation. Workers start in Scheduler's local itself, but not the desired machines. How do i start workers remotely in desired machines connecting to same scheduler?
2. I need `client` created in the `async` function to use in multiple `submit`, `map`, calls over time. Also I have many custom python functions. So, how do I programatically create workers on different machines, create a `client` and use it over time outside of async function. I tried following, unsuccessfully.

````
s_address = "x.x.x.x:8786" # remote scheduler IP

async def f():
    async with Worker(s_address) as w1, Worker(s_address) as w2:
        async with Client(s_address, asynchronous=True) as client:
            return client

client_to_use = f() # expecting client object which I can use and...
                    # ...when everything finishes, hoping context manager kills the workers.
                    # This clearly doesn't work
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(f()) # not sure if this is valid anymore

# What I need to do
custom_module.call_some_fn_to_use_dask_client(client_to_use) # Does not work as well!! ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You should read up the various options available to you to [setup dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup.html). In short, you need a way to talk to the machine on which you want to launch workers. The scheduler doesn't know how to do this, and the local client doesn't know how to do this, you need to pick the mechanism yourself. It can be as simple as logging into a remote machine and launching the worker process (i.e,. running python), but there are some much more complicated systems such as supercomputer schedulers, yarn and kubernetes.

The docs for [`Worker`](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/master/distributed/worker.py#L91) make clear that you are instantiating *here* where the call happens.

Before going further, you should maybe consider what it is that you're trying to achieve, and dexcribe that...

Comment: Thanks. What I am trying to achieve is this - I have huge RAM held up in dask workers because of pure python functions. I cannot avoid those. So, I thought of dynamically starting workers for a job and close all the workers down when done.

Comment: If you look at the deployment options, you'll see many that can manually or automatically scale the numbers of workers. dask-gateway also allows you to interface with any number of dynamically-created schedulers.